# WRAP Option wrap the word before it exceeds the length

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am generating the PDF using Apache FOP. I want to wrap the text if and only if exceeds the table-cell length. I tried with wrap-option="wrap". It splits the word when it finds the space itself.It does not look at the length of table-cell exceeds or not.

```
<fo:table width="33%" table-layout="fixed" position="fixed" margin-top="-21.5%" margin-left="68.5%"> 
  <fo:table-body> 
    <fo:table-row> 
      <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="3px" text-align="left" width="5cm" margin-left="1.2cm"> 
        <fo:block-container> 
          <fo:block wrap-option="wrap"> 
            <fo:inline font-family="TimesNewRoman" font-weight="bold"> 
              <xsl:value-of select="test/test1"/> 
            </fo:inline> 
          </fo:block> 
        </fo:block-container> 
      </fo:table-cell> 
    </fo:table-row> 
  </fo:table-body> 
</fo:table>
```

For example : I have a string like below :

```
 TEST 1 TEST 2 TEST 3
```

When i generate the PDF using above XSLT, it is displaying like below

```
 TEST
 1
 TEST
 2
 TEST
 3
```

Eventhough, it has more width, it is splitting and displaying.

How i would like to display is

```
TEST 1 TEST ..if length exceeds the length
2 TEST 3
```

[image]

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Can you add the actual FO XML markup for the `fo:table-cell`?  Can you add a screenshot of the formatted table cell?  What you describe isn't what I'd expect to happen, either.  Are you setting a margin or start-indent for the `fo:table`?  Does this happen for all columns or just in one column?

Comment: It is happening all the  column. Also i am setting margin property for that table cell.

Comment: <fo:table width="33%" table-layout="fixed" position="fixed" margin-top="-21.5%" margin-left="68.5%">
 <fo:table-body>
  <fo:table-row>
   <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="3px" text-align="left" width="5cm" margin-left="1.2cm">
    <fo:block-container>
     <fo:block wrap-option="wrap">
      <fo:inline font-family="TimesNewRoman" font-weight="bold">
       <xsl:value-of select="test/test1"/>
      </fo:inline>
     </fo:block>
    </fo:block-container>
   </fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>
 </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>

Answer (score 1):

Add `start-indent="0pt"` on `fo:table-body`:

```
<fo:table width="33%" table-layout="fixed"
      position="fixed" margin-top="-21.5%" margin-left="68.5%">
  <fo:table-body start-indent="0pt">
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="3px" text-align="left" width="5cm">
        <fo:block>
          <fo:inline font-family="TimesNewRoman" font-weight="bold"
         > TEST 1 TEST 2 TEST 3 </fo:inline>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

The `fo:table/@margin-left` was setting the inherited `start-indent` value that is used when working out the `start-indent` trait for the contents of each `fo:table-cell`.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#refine-margin-space-indent for details.

Also, the `fo:table-cell/@margin-left`, the `fo:block-container`, and the `fo:block/@wrap-option` weren't adding anything.

Comment: Also i would like to set that table cell to particular position. I tried with <fo:table-cell  position="absoulte" left="100px"></fo:table-cell>. it does not work for me.Can you kindly let me know, what i have to do in this scenario

Comment: Please start another question explaining exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks Tony Graham.  I have fixed above issue

Comment: @RajeshChandrasekar as this answer solved your problem, consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), so that future users with a similar problem can see it was useful.